# Selenuim webdriver fails without notice for ssl error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenuim webdriver to get a page with https scheme. if i go to the page using chrome i get the 'privacy error' and the response is empty.
If i use webdriver to get the page the webdriver stay on the last page it was in. How can i detect the webdriver did not move to the new page ?

I thought about checking if the driver.current_url is same as the url i want but it doesnt feel like the right solution.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://doman.com/1.html')  # this return 200 status and content
driver.get('https://domain2.com/2.html') # this return the privacy error 
# so the driver is still at the first url
```

Comment: Have you tried using **webdriver.common.utils.is_url_connectable** and see it catches the error and not connectable?

Comment: @Anzel but this will make another request. also it goes to hardcoded localserver

Comment: that will be a limitation I guess, or you can simply wrap in a try/except for timeout and see if new page is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have found a solution after reading [support desired_capabilities: acceptSslCerts=True](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/233)

```
from selenium import webdriver

service_args = ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true']
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=service_args)
driver.get('http://doman.com/1.html')
driver.get('https://domain2.com/2.html')  # now it returns 404 as it should
```